# Responsive table columns

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have this table:

```
-------------------------
| foo  |  bar   |  foo  |
-------------------------
| foo  |  bar   |  foo  |
-------------------------
```

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to transform it in:

```
--------
| foo  |
--------
| bar  |
--------
| foo  |
--------
| foo  |
--------
| bar  |
--------
| foo  |
--------
```

It would be easy, just add:

```
td { display: block; }
```

The problem is that this trick doesn't work with the DOCTYPE of my document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

How can I make it works with this DOCTYPE?

**N.B I can't edit HTML and I can't use JS**

Comment: Are we supposed to guess how your DOM looks like?

Comment: it's a table, what do you need, the html of a table?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to fix this, the Doctype triggers Quirks mode. It is turning on lots of old browser bugs, including limitations of `display` for table cells.

Comment: no ways with pseudo-elements, clearfixes and other tricks?